# EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, wordpress, ssl, autoblogged

I developed a GUI python using custom Tkinter for AutoBlogging articles on Wordpress, But when publishing like two articles it doesn't continue it gives me the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\karim\Downloads\ctk\examples\complex_example.py", line 321, in start_threading
image = client.call(UploadFile(image_data))
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordpress_xmlrpc\base.py", line 37, in call
raw_result = server_method(*args)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1122, in __call__
return self.__send(self.__name, args)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1464, in __request
response = self.__transport.request(
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1178, in single_request
http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1291, in send_request
self.send_content(connection, request_body)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1321, in send_content
connection.endheaders(request_body)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1076, in _send_output
self.send(chunk)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 998, in send
self.sock.sendall(data)
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1237, in sendall
v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
File "C:\Users\karim\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1206, in send
return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)
```

```py
if self.entry1.get().lower() == "uploaded":
        print("Let's go woohooo!... `\n")
        # WordPress API endpoint and credentials
        url = 'https://blablablabla.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php'
        username = 'upupupupup@gmail.com'
        password = 'upupupupup'

        # Pexels API endpoint and authentication token
        pexels_url = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search'
        pexels_api_key = 'PEXELS_API_KEY

        # Create a client instance for WordPress
        client = Client(url, username, password)
        # Input the title and content of the article
        file_path = 'titles.txt'
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            titles = file.read().split(',')
        
        articles = []
        for i, title in enumerate(titles):
            content = App.generate_articles(title, "Academic", 1500)
            #articles.append({'title': title.strip(), 'content': content.strip()})
            #title = articles['title']
            #content = articles['content']
            self.toplevel_window.article_label2.configure(text="ARTICLE NUMBER : "+str(num_article))
            kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(top=10, stopwords=None)
            keywords = kw_extractor.extract_keywords(title)
            i = 0
            v_new = []
            for kw, v in keywords:
                v_new.append(v)
                i += 1
                image_title = kw
            
                break
                
                                # Set up the request headers for Pexels API
            headers = {
                'Authorization': pexels_api_key
            }

            print(image_title)
            # Send a GET request to Pexels API for image search

            response = requests.get(pexels_url, headers=headers, params={'query': ''.join(image_title), 'per_page': 1}, verify=True)

            # Parse the JSON response
            data = response.json()
            time.sleep(1)
            # Extract the list of photos from the response
            photos = data.get('photos', [])

            # Check if any photos are found
            if photos:
                photo_url = photos[0]['src']['original']
                image_path = image_path = f"{i+1}_{keywords[0]}_{keywords[1]}.jpg"  # Customize the image file name as desired

                # Send a GET request to download the image
                image_response = requests.get(photo_url)

                # Save the image to a file
                with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
                    image_file.write(image_response.content)
            else:
                print("No suitable image found.")

            # Create a new WordPress post
            post = WordPressPost()
            post.title = title
            post.content = content

            # Set the desired categories for the post
            categories = [image_title]
            post.terms_names = {
                'category': categories  # Specify the desired categories
            }

            # Upload and attach the image to the post
            if photos:
                with open(image_path, 'rb') as img:
                    image_data = {
                        'name': image_path,
                        'type': 'image/jpeg',
                        'bits': img.read(),
                    }

                image = client.call(UploadFile(image_data))
                post.thumbnail = image['id']

            post.post_status = 'publish'  # Set post status to publish

            # Publish the post
            post_id = client.call(NewPost(post))

            print(f"Post '{title}' created successfully with ID: {post_id}")

    else:
        pass
```

[image]

I tried to add `Verify=True` in the requests but it doesn't work;
has anyone face this problem before? Please let me know if there is anything I can do because I've been facing this problem a long time. I didn't find any valid solution.

Comment: You have typos and mis-matched quotes in your code. It will not compile. Please fix them in the posting.

Comment: `pexels_api_key = 'PEXELS_API_KEY` This line is missing the closing quote.

Comment: Actually it's not typos errors as i mentioned the error is : EOF occurred in violation of protocol